# In a Java Spring Boot based cloud function how does one access the HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-functions

The examples for Spring Boot cloud functions for GCP are very simplistic at this point. Looking at the function-sample-gcp-http the main class looks like the following.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudFunctionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudFunctionMain.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> function() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Let's assume we are going to be writing something more complex than this as a cloud function and request method and headers are needed and maybe other things from the request or response. How would one, in the above 'function' access the HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse? Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Which HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse?  How do you expect this function to tie into the servlet request/response architecture?  Here's an article explaining one such answer to your and these questions: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud functions with spring boot uses the [Spring Cloud Functions](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function) framework, that don't let you the capability to access to the HTTPservlet lower level API.

However, in the Java Cloud Function Alpha mailing list, the question has been raised. I haven't visibility on this (in the roadmap or not, and if in the roadmap, for when), but the product team is aware of this limitation (especially if you want to return your own error code (400, 401, 403, 405, 406, 429, 501,...))